# Pyinstaller with pywinauto huge file size

Tags: python, pyinstaller, pywinauto

I have a script that I want to compile into an executable. I'm using Pyinstaller for this task and the exe file generated is too large.

There are several imports, one of them is **pywinauto**. If I comment pywinauto imports I get an executable with 20mb. With pywinauto I get an executable with 232mb!

Note: I'm running pyinstaller from a virtual environment in which I have just installed the necessary python dependencies that I'm using in the script.

Here is a list of the imports I'm using:

```
import os,subprocess,datetime, argparse, math, win32con
import boto3
from botocore.exceptions import NoCredentialsError
from botocore.client import Config
import wx,wx.adv
from pubsub import pub
from win32api import GetSystemMetrics

from pywinauto.application import Application
from pywinauto.keyboard import SendKeys
from pywinauto.findwindows import find_window

from base64 import b64decode
from zlib import decompress
from io import BytesIO
```

Pyinstaller command that I'm running:
`pyinstaller --noconsole --onefile --i=rec.ico --clean script.py`

`pip list` in my virtal environment:

```
Package         Version
--------------- --------
boto3           1.9.246
botocore        1.12.246
comtypes        1.1.7
docutils        0.15.2
jmespath        0.9.4
Pillow          6.2.0
pip             19.2.3
pubsub          0.1.2
pypiwin32       223
python-dateutil 2.8.0
pywin32         225
pywinauto       0.6.7
s3transfer      0.2.1
setuptools      40.8.0
six             1.12.0
urllib3         1.25.6
wheel           0.33.6
wxPython        4.0.6
```

Is there any way to reduce the executable size?

I'm using pywinauto basically to send a keyboard shortcut command to another application from my script. If there's an alternative library to do this that would make my executable smaller I would certainly try it.

Thanks!

====================

EDIT:

I tried to compile with:
`pyinstaller --noconsole --onedir --i=rec.ico --clean script.py`

Now I get a folder with 660mb!!! And the application loads WAY faster (it was taking about 15s to load before, now it's almost instantly).

The folder of the application has a LOT of dll files, the 19 largest of them  summing up to 537 Mb.

[image: Screenshot of the largest files in the folder]

Any suggestions on how to trim that?

Comment: Can you try to pack `pywin32` package only without pywinauto and without comtypes?

Comment: Not sure if that's what you meant, but here's what I tried based on your comment:
I went to my virtual environment and did `pip uninstall comtypes` and the same for pywinauto. Then I compiled the exe with pyinstaller: `pyinstaller --noconsole --onefile --i=rec.ico --clean script.py`, with the same imports as above. Gave me an executable with 232mb.

Comment: The problem is definitely not in pywinauto. MKL and TBB are Intel libraries. Are you using Intel Python distribution? It's interesting how you've become depending on them. `pywinauto` doesn't use them for sure. I'd suggest to check `import math` if it's Intel Python distro.

Comment: BTW, you have a duplicated installation: `pypiwin32==223` and `pywin32==225`. The second one in the current official `pyWin32` package.

Comment: I'm using Anaconda Python distribution. What got me thinking It was pywinauto is that if I remove It from the imports I get a 10x smaller exe file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I did a fresh install of python 3.7, since I was using Anaconda's Python distribution before, installed just the packages I needed and compiled it with pyinstaller again. Now I have a 35Mb file with `--onefile` or a 120Mb folder with `--onedir`. I'll probably be using onedir because the application loads faster that way. I don't think it's the ideal file size but it's certaily way better than before (open to suggestions in case anyone has an idea on how to further reduce the size of the application). Thanks Vasily for the help!

Comment: It's possible to exclude some more unnecessary modules from an executable using `excludes` list in `setup.py`. It should be easy to find some guides about that. After a number of experiments and full re-builds I believe ~20 Mb one file can be achieved.

Comment: BTW, you can mark your own answer as accepted (gray check box at left side) to improve `pywinauto` tag statistics. Thanks!